# Can you use COUNT() in a SOQL query from SOAP API?

Tags: soql, soap-api, java

I want to use the Java SOAP API to execute a query like the following:

```
connection.query("SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Contact WHERE . . .");
```

However I get back a single SObject:

```
[SObject  fieldsToNull='{[0]}'
 Id='null'
]
```

Is there a correct way to do this without querying for all the records and using the size of the `.getRecords()` array?

Luckily in my case there are less than 200 records as a result of this query so it wouldn't be the end of the world...

Edit -

It has been suggested to use aliasing combined with a "GROUP BY" - however this results in multiple null SObjects being returned instead of just an integer count.

Comment: As per the docs, this should work: String soqlQuery = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact"; try { QueryResult qr = connection.query(soqlQuery);  From - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_walk_through_code.htm

Comment: Andy, as stated in the original question I know this will work, however I am trying to use the COUNT() function instead of querying for records.

Comment: The syntax is different. You ought to try to pass a variable into connection.query method. For example, try this: String soqlQuery = "SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Contact WHERE..."); try{ QueryResult qr = connection.query(soqlQuery);

Comment: I am sorry but this is exactly what I tried and gives the same result as in the original question. The only difference is that you are creating a variable with a reference to the String and passing the reference instead of passing the string directly.

Comment: Have you tried aliasing the count field? `[Select Count(Id) NrRecs FROM....]`? Otherwise the field name will be null. And, by the way, you will only get one record from that query unless you have a "Group By" clause.

Comment: What if you remove `Id` from the parens? That is, `COUNT()` instead of `COUNT(Id)`?

Comment: @SebastianKessel, yes - I think you must be right. An example would be: ("SELECT COUNT(Id) idCount FROM Contact GROUP BY (Email)");

Comment: @AdrianLarson - this results in a MalformedQuery error.

Comment: @SebastianKessel - This actually retrieves many SObject records with null value. This is a little closer to what I am looking for, but no better than querying for objects themselves instead of COUNT(Id).

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the following query:

`connection.query("SELECT CreatedById, Count(Id) numOfLeads FROM Lead GROUP BY CreatedById");`

The `QueryResult` will contain records of type `AggregateResult extends SObject` which is basically a wrapper for each row in the response. You must provide the name for each needed field, the count result here is aliased as `"numOfLeads"`:

`String userId = (String) myRecord.getField("CreatedById");
 int createdLeads = (int) myRecord.getField("numOfLeads");`

Comment: You can alias the field to any name you want (e.g. `SELECT COUNT(Id) recordCount FROM Lead` and then `aggregate.get('recordCount')`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the count of SOQL records but you have to apply LIMIT of 50000 as Salesforce has a SOQL query rows limit. This is referenced in [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_countQuery).

[image]

You can you also use SOAP API on visualforce page:

[image]

Example of AggregateResult: Count() using in SOQL via SOAP API:

```
<apex:page >
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
        </script>
        <script src="../../soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script>

        var query = "SELECT Count(id) cnts FROM case WHERE Status='new' ";
        var result = sforce.connection.query(query);
        console.log(result);
        document.write('Getting AggregateResult records:<br/>');
        var records = result.getArray("records");
        if(records.length>0)
        document.write('Aggregate Count: ' + records[0]['cnts']+'<br/>');

        var query1 = "SELECT Count() FROM case WHERE Status='new' ";
        var result1 = sforce.connection.query(query1);
        console.log(result1);
        document.write('======================<br/>');
        document.write('Getting query result<br/>');
        var records1 = result1.getArray("records");// no records are found because query will return count
        var counts= result1.get("size");
        document.write('Count of records are:' + counts); 

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I think the OP is concerned about how to get values back over the SOAP API and not directly in Apex code.

Comment: Modified my Answer according SOAP API uses.

Comment: Please see @SebastianKessel's comment above - this certainly does not work from the SOAP API using Java unless there is a "GROUP BY" statement in the query, and even then multiple records are returned instead of just a single integer value like I want.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Yes you can use Count() in SOQL via SOAP API, the previous example we related to AggregateResult but I update my answer having Both Example of AggregateResult and use of Count() In SOQL via SOAP API, so you can also use both is SOQL in another form of SOAP API like that.